# How do I convert a character into ascii code?

Tags: enumerate, counters, enumitem, conversion

I have a custom enumerator:

```
\newenvironment{subp}{%
  \begin{enumerate}[label={\textsc{\alph*.}}]
}{\end{enumerate}}
```

In the environment sometimes I need to skip to specific labels, I will do it like:

```
\begin{subp}
  \setcounter{enumi}{1} % b
  \item blah blah

  \setcounter{enumi}{4} % e
  \item blah blah
\end
```

Since the labels are in alphabet and the counter was counted in numeral.

I wish I can write a macro that looks like:

```
\newcommand{\setcurrentlabel}[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{\toascii{#1}-\toascii{a}}
```

Perhaps there is some conversion macro `\toascii` that works just like `ord(x)` function in python. So I can use `\setcurrentlabel{b}` directly, which is more clear than setting `enumi` manually with a number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The back tick can be used to get the character code in numerical contexts:

```
`a or `\a
```

The numerical context can be provided by `\number` or the following example uses e-TeX's `\numexpr` for the subtraction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\setcurrentlabel}[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{\numexpr`#1-`a\relax}}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}
\begin{enumerate}
  \setcurrentlabel{b}
  \item blah blah

  \setcurrentlabel{e}
  \item blah blah
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

An alternative is package `calc`:

```
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand*{\setcurrentlabel}[1]{\setcounter{enumi}{`#1-`a}}
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I don't understand is why you put a `\renewcommand*{\theenumi}{\alph{enumi}}` in prior to the enumerate environment.

Comment: @ShouYa That's the “`enumerate` free” version. Just do your own way and it will work.

Comment: Also called "reverse apostrophe or left quote" according to the TeXBook. _____________________________________________________________________________________________ To clarify on the "numerical context" part, for example ​``​`a`` will not automatically expand to 97, but ``\number`a`` will, similarly for `"1A`. See also "integer constant" in TeXBook. For LaTeX3 `int_eval` / `int_value` can be used in place of `\number`.

Answer (score 1):

For the amount of effort to set the numeric label, you might just as well use the optional argument typically supported by `\item`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\fixeditem}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\item}% \fixeditem
    {\item[\scshape #1.]}% \fixeditem[..]
}

\newlist{subp}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subp]{label={\textsc{\alph*.}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subp}
  \item blah blah

  \fixeditem[b] blah blah

  \fixeditem[e] blah blah
\end{subp}

\end{document}
```

The only drawback about the above approach is when you intermix `\item`s with `\fixeditem`s. The list enumeration will not continue sequentially after a `\fixeditem`.